# Percona xtrabackup

Tags: mysql, database-backups, mariadb, percona

I installed percona xtrabackup on CentOS-6 and it installed just fine. However, i cannot seem to find any blog or documentation that shows how to configure or run xtrabackup to actually backup my databases. I would like to configure an automatic backup if possible. Can anybody show me how this is done, or point me to some site that shows step-by-step how to backup databases using percona xtrabackup?

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.percona.com/doc/percona-xtrabackup/2.1/how-tos.html

Comment: Does Xtrabackup provide automated backup without using third party scripts? I was looking more to automate the backup and restiration process. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply setup a cron job with the parameters and values.

For example: This does a compressed backup to the /backup folder every night.

```
0 0 * * * innobackupex --stream=tar --user=<user> --password=<pass> ./ 2>&1 | gzip - > /backup/backup-db-`date +\%Y\%m\%d`.tar.gz
```

Answer (score 0):

You can download the Percona XtraBackup User Manual for free [here](https://www.percona.com/software/mysql-database/percona-xtrabackup)